# Swift : Recursively calling a function with an enum type as a parameter

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I found this code at apple swift documentation

```
indirect enum ArithmeticExpression {
    case Number(Int)
    case Addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
    case Multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
}

func evaluate(expression: ArithmeticExpression) -> Int {
    switch expression {
    case .Number(let value):
        return value
    case .Addition(let left, let right):
        return evaluate(left) + evaluate(right)
    case .Multiplication(let left, let right):
        return evaluate(left) * evaluate(right)
    }
}

// evaluate (5 + 4) * 2
let five = ArithmeticExpression.Number(5)
let four = ArithmeticExpression.Number(4)
let sum = ArithmeticExpression.Addition(five, four)
let product = ArithmeticExpression.Multiplication(sum, ArithmeticExpression.Number(2))
print(evaluate(product))
// prints "18"
```

i don't quit understand how the recursion is happening in here and why a constant declaration is being declared as a parameter in the return statement in the returning line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it as a tree. Nodes=Expressions. Constants=Leaves.

[image: <ruslanspivak.com>re]

(image source ruslanspivak.com)

While traversing it - you examine each of the two operands. If it's an expression, you need to compute it, so you call on 'evaluate' with this operand. If it's a constant, think of it like a result - it's just a number, so no more calculations are needed. 
In the end, we ALWAYS get to a constants (=leaves) it is then when the the stack starts to fold and the values results return "up" in the tree to add up to the total result.

For more diving into the subject I recommend googling "binary expression tree".

(By the way, the code example does not tend for priorities. The multiplication is computed before the addition only because the order of calls.
If we really wanted to take care of priorities : e.g. "(", ")" over "*" , "/", a stack for operations would have been needed here.)